Show that $\frac{a^2+c^2}{ad+bc}$ is irreducible.
The problem
Let $a,b,c,d \in N^*$. If $ab-cd=1$, then show that $\frac{a^2+c^2}{ad+bc}$ is irreducible.
my idea
I thought of using the  Brahmagupta - Fibonacci Identity and got that $(a^2+c^2)(d^2+b^2)=(ad+cb)^2+ (ab-cd)^2$
Also because that relation equals $1$ we can always multiply by it and it doesn't change anything.
I also thought of letting $g$ BE the greatest common divisor between $a^2+c^2,  ad+bc$ and then show that $g=1$
I hope one of you can help me!

Its Not a Lagrange's Identity, its called Brahmagupta - Fibonacci Identity. edit this in your question.

I also thought it's Lagrange @Guruprasad

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity History of Theory of Numbers by Eugene Dickson book also Has a Name : Brahmagupta - Fibonacci Identity

You're nearly done already.
$(a^2+c^2)(d^2+b^2)=(ad+cb)^2+ (ab-cd)^2$
$(a^2+c^2)(d^2+b^2)=(ad+cb)^2+ 1$
Two consecutive numbers are always coprime*. So $(a^2+c^2)(d^2+b^2)$ is coprime to $(ad+cb)^2$.
Anything that divides $a^2+c^2$ also divides $(a^2+c^2)(d^2+b^2)$, so $a^2+c^2$ is also coprime to $(ad+cb)^2$.
Anything that divides $ad+cb$ divides $(ad+cb)^2$, so $a^2+c^2$ is also coprime to $ad+cb$.
And since its numerator and denominator are coprime, $\frac{a^2+c^2}{ad+cb}$ is irreducible.

* if $n$ divides $(ad+cb)^2$ and $n$ divides $(ad+cb)^2+1$, then $n$ divides their difference. Which is 1. So their only common divisor is 1, so they're coprime.

@ChristopherWellsChrist Thanks so much for your idea. You said that the 2 terms are coprime because $(a^2+c^2)(d^2+b^2)= M_{(ad+cb)^2}+1$? Is my reasoning ok? also why did the conclusion follows?

I added more detail. Is it clearer now.
